# Understanding air permeation of a material

Tags: atmospheric-science, air, diffusion

I am trying to research on acceptable materials to hold an atmosphere inside of a vacuum. Understanding that air will escape at different rates through all materials, I don't know what the property is called.

I am expecting to be able to find some coefficient that is measured in units similar to $L/(N*m*s)$ likely with different prefixes, but a unit of volume per area, thickness, pressure and time hence $N*m*s$. Does such a property exist for materials and a specific gas going through?

I believe I have found a property similar known as air permeation, but it doesn't seem to be exactly what I'm looking for since what I want to know is how much air will leak out at 1 atm into the lunar environment which is effectively a vacuum at all times since the vessel would be small. Any help on finding this information for various materials would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think that just about any metal of any significant thickness (say, at least 1mm) is virtually impermeable to an "air-like" nitrogen-oxygen atmosphere for any practical time scales you would be interested in.

Comment: The problem is that I need a high amount of flexibility